# Given two sets $A,\; B$ and that $|A| = |B|$, show that $|2^A| = |2^B|$

Tags: analysis

Given two sets $A,\; B$ and that $|A| = |B|$, show that $|2^A| = |2^B|$.

Intuitively, I think this is true, but I am having trouble showing this formally.

I know that there exists a bijection $f: A \to B$ and that we should try to define a map $g: 2^A \to 2^B$ so that we can show $g$ is bijective. However, I am stuck on defining $g$.

Comment: Hint: an element of $2^A$ is a subset. Apply $g$ to each element.

Comment: I think what @KevinCarlson means is to apply $f$ to each element of the subset of $A$; that is $g(U) = \{f(u): u \in U\}$ where $U \in 2^A$.

Comment: Hint: a function is injective if and only if the induced forward-image function is injective. Similarly, a function is surjective if and only if the induced forward-image function is surjective.

Comment: @Tom yes, thanks for catching that.